# Using r shiny observeEvent with a downloadHandler

Tags: r, shiny, observers

I am challenged by the process of using an observer to observe the action of creating a CSV file for download. I think that the R-Studio documentation states that eventExpr may be a "complex expression inside curly braces." Is this a valid eventExpression? I am using this construct 5 times, and all five conditions are triggered when my shinyApp initiates.

```
    observeEvent(
        {
        ### Observe the download handler preparing for CSV download
        output$Wire_Centers.csv <- downloadHandler(
            filename = "Wire_Centers.csv",
            content = function(file) {
                write.table(WC_List_2(), file, row.names=FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep=',') ### end write.table
                } # End content function
            ) # End downloadHandler
            }, { # End observered event, start log
        logUse("WC_Download")
        }) # end observeEvent output condition
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? observeEvent is typically set up as `observeEvent(input$some_element, {...})` where `input$some_element` is something in the app that can be interacted with, which causes `observeEvent` to run whatever code is inside of the curly braces.

Comment: Thanks, brittenb. I am trying to log the fact that the user selected the CSV download. The function logUse("WC_Download") is just appending an Rds datafile with the systime, userID and the action taken. My challenge is that I am attempting to trigger off of the downloadHandler() action. It does not seem like a valid construct. I also tried action buttons, but I could not embed the downloadHandler() in the action clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished adding the activity log action by adding the log function call as the first clause of the content function for the downloadHandler. The call `logUse("WC_Download")` operates as required, and the activity log is appropriately augmented.

```
    output$Wire_Centers.csv <- downloadHandler(
        filename = "Wire_Centers.csv",
        content = function(file) {
            logUse("WC_Download")
            write.table(WC_List_2(), file, row.names=FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep=',') ### end write.table
            }, # End content function
        ) # End downloadHandler
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, all five are being called at startup. The code isn't tied to an input$ or other change, so it just runs and it reports that it *started*. Consider if you want it to report after the download finishes or if you want to run the code on user input.

Comment: Thanks, Chris Buck. I agree. My Observers did work when I used input$value as the trigger, but I could not find a way to use an input$value with the download handler. But I did find a way to accomplish the required logging action by putting the log function call as the first clause of the content function for the dounload handler. See below: